# How to let a signal flow only if it lasted for at least 500ms

Tags: pcb-design, 555

I'm starting to work on PCBs and I need to make a circuit letting the signal flow only if it lasted at least 500ms. I tried using a 555timer but I didn't find a proper usage for it since I don't want to output a pulse but a positive signal only if the required duration is met. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: What kind of signal? What voltage levels? What does "output a positive signal" mean?  Is your signal digital or analog?  Are you saying you want to output a 500 ms delayed version of your input only if the input lasted for 500 ms, otherwise output nothing (zero?).  We need more details to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: You do realize that whatever method you come up with won't be able to see into the future to know if the signal is going to last at least 500ms or not? So the output will always be 500ms shorter than the input or the same length, but delayed by 500ms.

Comment: Also, 90% of questions about 555 on this site get a comment: "use microcontroller instead".

Comment: @jaskij - I guess this time it's yours, lol

Comment: @JohnD I would have 12V dc and what I meant is that I want to have 12V if my input signal is active since at least 500ms and 0V else. My bad for the unclear question.

Comment: @brhans I know this the delay is not a problem I am building a safety system that would activate only if my error is signaled for at least 500ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I am also pretty new and pioneering in electronics but if you have your switch between the +5V and R1 (now connected left to NODE1) you get the graph below, showing +5V at NODE3 only after ~500ms. Please let me know what you think! This is assuming that the switch stays closed of course. But this in combination with the 555 in monostable mode (using NODE3 as a trigger) should also keep the signal high after disconnecting the switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwir6j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

My idea was to slowly charge C1 via R1 while Q1 is off. When node 1 is at sufficient voltage (around 0.6-0.7 V) it turns on Q1 and pulls node 2 to ground, turning Q2 of, disconnecting node 3 from ground. Then you get your 5 V signal at node 3.

Comment: I would love to know how to get a steeper slope though. With this setup I seem to be only able to move it in time, but not to alter its steepness.

Comment: @Neils I guess it could work I need to thy this thank you

Comment: Run the simulation with a shorter time step. You have it set to 50ms, so that's what's making the output slope look so slow.

Comment: I was just going to say I figured this out. Then it is pretty steep indeed. Thanks!

Comment: It looks to work pretty fine I have another mistake on the other side of my circuit so I need to correct it first to be sure your option works perfectly as I wished

Comment: The exact timing will depend on the temperature coefficient of the B-E junction of the transistor Q1, as well as the applied voltage V1. Also, there should be a resistor across the input, or across C1, to discharge it in a timely manner. Otherwise it depends on the leakage currents of C1 and Q1.

Comment: I work perfectly thank you very much for this solution @Niels

Comment: @PStechPaul I put it accross the input, after the switch. I think that would be correct.